# How do I return an individual cell value instead of the entire row. Excel to Python Tkinter

Tags: python, excel, tkinter

I would like to know how to return a single cell value (A2) when I click the <kbd>Get Prideful</kbd> button. Instead of returning the entire (A) column.

When I try to type:

```
Prideful = ws['A2']
```

instead of:

```
Prideful = ws['A']
```

This error comes up when I click the <kbd>Get Prideful</kbd> button:

> "TypeError: 'Cell' object is not iterable"

Here is the full code:

```
from tkinter import *
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

root = Tk()
root.title("The Book of Wisdom")
root.geometry("500x500")

wb = Workbook()
wb = load_workbook('Test_Workbook.xlsx')
ws = wb.active


Prideful = ws['A']
Happy = ws['B']

# Prideful Button ------------------------------------------------

def Prideful_list():
    list = '' 
    for cell in Prideful:
        list = f'{list + str(cell.value)}\n'
        Prideful_label.config(text=list)


button_Prideful = Button(root, text="Get Prideful", command=Prideful_list)
button_Prideful.pack()

Prideful_label = Label(root, text="")
Prideful_label.pack()

# Happy Button ------------------------------------------------

def Happy_list():
    list = ''
    for cell in Happy:
        list = f'{list + str(cell.value)}\n'
        Happy_label.config(text=list)

button_Happy = Button(root, text="Get Happy", command=Happy_list)
button_Happy.pack()

Happy_label = Label(root, text="")
Happy_label.pack()



root.mainloop()
# END ==============================================================
```

Comment: If you use `Prideful = ws['A2']`, you should not use for loop inside `Prideful_list()` function as `Prideful` has only one cell data.

Answer (score 0):

as the error message says, you tried iterating on Cell object.
You set `ws['A2']` to `Prideful` and executed for loop on `Prideful` but it seems that Cell object does not support iteration.

If you want to add some flexibility to your code so that you can iterate base on rows or columns, try:

```
for row in range(x):
    for column in range(y):
        value = ws.cell(row, column).value
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!